# How do i use yumrepo in Puppet to add the Docker repos?

Tags: puppet

Per the Docker documentation, the list of yum repositories are added by this command:

```
yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

I'd like to have Puppet do this for me, so I was hoping this would work:

```
yumrepo { "docker":
    descr => 'docker',
    baseurl => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo',
    enabled => 1
}
```

But, this doesn't work.

Unfortunately, the URL used in the yum-config-manager contains an entire list of name/baseurl/enabled/gpgcheck/gpgkey entries, where the yumrepo is expecting just one of those. So, is there a way to add the entire list of entries in the docker URL with one yumrepo command, or some other command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL in the Docker instructions is that of a .repo file to be installed on the system.  *The contents* of such a file are what the properties of a `Yumrepo` resource describe.  Applying a `Yumrepo` resource involves managing the contents of repository description files, not obtaining external files from somewhere else, whether via `yum-config-manager` or otherwise.

You have many options, but here are some of the more likely ones:

- Obtain the specified file from docker.com, store it in your module's `files` directory, and install and manage it on target nodes via a `File` resource.
- Install the repo file on some node that also has Puppet, and use the [`puppet resource`](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/man/resource.html) command to obtain Puppet DSL representations of the Yumrepo resources that result.  Put these into a suitable class on the master.

Answer (score 1):

Or alternatively you can peak inside `docker-ce.repo` and write proper yumrepo config:

```
[docker-ce-stable]
name=Docker CE Stable - $basearch
baseurl=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/$releasever/$basearch/stable
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg
```

into:

```
yumrepo { 'docker-ce-stable':
   name     => 'Docker CE Stable',
   baseurl  => 'https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/$releasever/$basearch/stable',
   enabled  => 1,
   gpgcheck => 1,
   gpgkey   => https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/gpg',
}
```

which looks straightforward and could be generated once from `docker-ce.repo` file via `sed` or other tools.